# Business Data Connector List Column not working BDC XML Definition

Tags: 2007, filter, bdc-model, business-data-catalog, sql

I have a BDC connected to a SQL Table with 2500 Rows. I'm able to add a Business Data List WP to a page and point it to the BDC source and it looks fine except for limited number of Rows.
However, if I add a Custom List column to the BDC. Several things are seemingly wrong.

1. I see a find dropdown to the left of my selection when I select the address book, but it's empty. What is this?
2. I get an error that over 200 entries were found, but I can't seem to filter
3. When I select an entry, I get some strange guid like value back.
4. Once I do get this working, it would be nice to wildcard search so If I enter "car", it would filter "Cars" and "The Cars".  I understand this is a matter of tweaking the select with like "%val%"

My table is actually a one column varchar(100) with Departments. No key, No ID. The column has a unique constraint.

My BDC XML definition is a hacked up copy of some other BDC that was much more complicated and generated by some utility we were demoing. :)  This is, of course, were my problems likely begin and end. I'd like to keep it simple.

Given that my table is Departments and column is Department.

Is this line what is returning that id? If so, not sure how to fix it so that I just get back Departments.Department

Name="dbo.[Departments]IDs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<LobSystem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/03/BusinessDataCatalog BDCMetadata.xsd" Type="Database" Version="1.0.0.0" Name="Departments" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/03/BusinessDataCatalog">
  <Properties>
    <Property Name="Departments" Type="System.String">%</Property>
  </Properties>
  <LobSystemInstances>
    <LobSystemInstance Name="Departments">
      <Properties>
        <Property Name="DatabaseAccessProvider" Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.ApplicationRegistry.SystemSpecific.Db.DbAccessProvider">SqlServer</Property>
        <Property Name="AuthenticationMode" Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.ApplicationRegistry.SystemSpecific.Db.DbAuthenticationMode">PassThrough</Property>
        <Property Name="RdbConnection Data Source" Type="System.String">XXXXXl</Property>
        <Property Name="RdbConnection Initial Catalog" Type="System.String">XXXXXXXXXX</Property>
        <Property Name="RdbConnection User ID" Type="System.String">xxxxxxxx</Property>
        <Property Name="RdbConnection Password" Type="System.String">xxxxxxxx</Property>
        <Property Name="RdbConnection Integrated Security" Type="System.String"></Property>
        <Property Name="RdbConnection Pooling" Type="System.String">false</Property>
      </Properties>
    </LobSystemInstance>
  </LobSystemInstances>
  <Entities>
    <Entity EstimatedInstanceCount="0" Name="dbo.Departments">
      <Properties>
        <Property Name="DefaultAction" Type="System.String">View Profile</Property>
      </Properties>
      <Identifiers>
        <Identifier TypeName="System.String" Name="[Department]" />
      </Identifiers>
      <Methods>
        <Method Name="Getdbo.[Departments]">
          <Properties>
            <Property Name="RdbCommandText" Type="System.String">Select [Department] From dbo.[Departments]</Property>
            <Property Name="RdbCommandType" Type="System.Data.CommandType, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">Text</Property>
          </Properties>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter Direction="Return" Name="dbo.[Departments]">
              <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.Data.IDataReader, System.Data, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" IsCollection="true" Name="dbo.[Departments]DataReader">
                <TypeDescriptors>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.Data.IDataRecord, System.Data, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Name="dbo.[Departments]DataRecord">
                    <TypeDescriptors>
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="[Department]" Name="Department" />
                    </TypeDescriptors>
                  </TypeDescriptor>
                </TypeDescriptors>
              </TypeDescriptor>
            </Parameter>
          </Parameters>
          <MethodInstances>
            <MethodInstance Type="Finder" ReturnParameterName="dbo.[Departments]" ReturnTypeDescriptorName="dbo.[Departments]DataReader" ReturnTypeDescriptorLevel="0" Name="dbo.[Departments]Finder" />
          </MethodInstances>
        </Method>
        <Method Name="dbo.[Departments]SpecificFinder">
          <Properties>
            <Property Name="RdbCommandText" Type="System.String">Select [Department] From dbo.[Departments] Where ([Department]=@Department)</Property>
            <Property Name="RdbCommandType" Type="System.Data.CommandType, System.Data, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">Text</Property>
          </Properties>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter Direction="In" Name="@Department">
              <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="[Department]" Name="[Department]" />
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter Direction="Return" Name="dbo.[Departments]">
              <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.Data.IDataReader, System.Data, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" IsCollection="true" Name="dbo.[Departments]DataReader">
                <TypeDescriptors>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.Data.IDataRecord, System.Data, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Name="dbo.[Departments]DataRecord">
                    <TypeDescriptors>
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="[Department]" Name="Department" />
                    </TypeDescriptors>
                  </TypeDescriptor>
                </TypeDescriptors>
              </TypeDescriptor>
            </Parameter>
          </Parameters>
          <MethodInstances>
            <MethodInstance Type="SpecificFinder" ReturnParameterName="dbo.[Departments]" ReturnTypeDescriptorName="dbo.[Departments]DataReader" ReturnTypeDescriptorLevel="0" Name="dbo.[Departments]SpecificFinder" />
          </MethodInstances>
        </Method>
        <Method Name="dbo.[Departments]IDEnumerator">
          <Properties>
            <Property Name="RdbCommandType" Type="System.Data.CommandType, System.Data, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">Text</Property>
            <Property Name="RdbCommandText" Type="System.String">Select [Department] from dbo.[Departments]</Property>
          </Properties>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter Direction="Return" Name="dbo.[Departments]IDs">
              <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.Data.IDataReader, System.Data, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" IsCollection="true" Name="dbo.[Departments]IDs">
                <TypeDescriptors>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.Data.IDataRecord, System.Data, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Name="dbo.[Departments]">
                    <TypeDescriptors>
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="[Department]" Name="Department" />
                    </TypeDescriptors>
                  </TypeDescriptor>
                </TypeDescriptors>
              </TypeDescriptor>
            </Parameter>
          </Parameters>
          <MethodInstances>
            <MethodInstance Type="IdEnumerator" ReturnParameterName="dbo.[Departments]IDs" ReturnTypeDescriptorName="dbo.[Departments]IDs" ReturnTypeDescriptorLevel="0" Name="dbo.[Departments]EnumeratorInstance" />
          </MethodInstances>
        </Method>
      </Methods>
    </Entity>
  </Entities>
</LobSystem>
```